# showing side by side comparison data in rdlc

Tags: .net, reporting, rdlc

we are going to implement RDLC reporting for showing patient lab test reports. one of the requirements is to show previous values (if any) of the last two same test results.

for example, if the patient report is for CBC test, we need to show each component and value for the current report as well as comparison of last 2 reports values.

e.g.

```
CBC 

Component                Normal Range        Result   
                                                  08-May-19     02-May   25-Apr

RBC                       100-150 Nos               122           102     160
WBC                       200-300 Nos               190           210     250
Lymph                     5-20                      6              4       9
```

the dataset to be returned can be assumed in following format

```
ResultId    OrderId  OrderDate    ComponentId  ComponentName   Range    Value

3             3      08-May-19       1          WBC            100-150   122
2             2      02-May-19       1          WBC            100-150   102
1             1      25-Apr-19       1          WBC            100-150   160

4             3      08-May-19       2          RBC            200-300   190
5             2      02-May-19       2          RBC            200-300   210
6             1      25-Apr-19       2          RBC            200-300   250

7             3      08-May-19       3          Lymph          5-20      6
8             2      02-May-19       3          Lymph          5-20      4
9             1      25-Apr-19       3          Lymph          5-20      9
```

as am completely new to rdlc, can anyone kindly guide whether this is achievable and if so, how (just a wild guess that this may be done through groupings)

any help appreciated

Comment: You can use matrix (http://www.gotreportviewer.com/matrices/) to aggregates data along two or more dimensions.

Comment: @tezzo thank you for the suggestion . will try to implement and inform asap